# passing model attributes to URL in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am new to Django. I have a model with 2 fields called id (as pk) and region.I have a page to return objects in each region.There are 10 regions and I need to pass region number to url to retrieve data from db filtering that region.
Here is my code :

**views.py**

```
def render_pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
pk = kwargs.get('pk')   *********here i need to get region from clicked button instead of pk*************
data = MyModel.objects.filter(region=pk)
template_path = 'pdf/Pdf.html'
context = {'data':data}
return response
```

**urls.py**

```
path('pdf/<pk>/', render_pdf_view, name='pdf-data') ***I need to pass region instead of pk***
```

**template**

```
<a href="{% url 'application : pdf-data' ? %}"> export pdf </a>
```

I don't know how to pass the region from clicked button to view and then pass it to url.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To pass your region from the template to the view you'd do this with the template;

```
<a href="{% url 'application:pdf-data' object.region %}"> export pdf </a>
```

Then the URL path needs to specify region;

```
path('pdf/<str:region>/', render_pdf_view, name='pdf-data')
```

And the view can then make use of that value.

```
def render_pdf_view(request, region, *args, **kwargs):

    data = MyModel.objects.filter(region=region)
    template_path = 'pdf/Pdf.html'
    context = {'data':data}
    return response
```

Comment: But when i want to use region in line `data = MyModel.objects.filter(region=region)` it does not know region.and also in template , from where i could find object?because i have many objects related to each region. @markwalker_

Comment: i have got this error : `Reverse for 'pdf-data' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['pdf/(?P<region>[^/]+)/$']` @markwalker_

Comment: Then if you've just copy/pasted my example, your context which renders the template doesn't include `object` so you'll need to make sure the context has the thing with the region you want to pass to that URL